# Facebook programmatically trigger re-parsing of url

Tags: parsing, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to make Facebook re-parse a page to get the updated open graph object?
I know about the linter debug tool but I was wondering if there's an API or something to do it programmatically.

Comment: Facebook crawls your urls about every 24 hours.

Answer (score 5):

According to the Facebook documentation located at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/defining-an-object/ under "Updating Objects"

```
curl -X POST \
  -F "id={object-url OR object-id}" \
  -F "scrape=true" \
  "https://graph.facebook.com"
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, is it not? @Nick-Dima, did this solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

all you have to do is hit http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q={escaped URL} with an authorized session.

I had to re-lint a couple thousand URLs so printed them out as basic links and then used a browser plugin to download them all so it only ended up taking 15 mins.